# QuartzCore/CAMetalLayer.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, metal

I try to check out the new Samples from the new Metal API for iOS.
When i download the code an open it in the XCode 6 Beta I'm getting the following error message:

```
QuartzCore/CAMetalLayer.h file not found
```

Do i need to add some other files or am I missing something else?
The Metal API should be available in OSX 10.9.3.

Is there any need to upgrade to Yosemite 10.10 Beta to run these examples?

Comment: as far as I know the Metal API is exclusively available in iOS 8, not in OS X

Comment: it seems like the Metal API isn't included in XCode 6, even if i add the Quarz Core Framework for iOS 8.

Comment: Use either "@import Metal" or "#import <Metal/Metal.h>. Works for the bundled Game template.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Reason behind this error is it only works in device having A7+ chip, simulator will not work for this.

Comment: what is the solution for this issue

Comment: The solutions is that you have to use devices(Simulator will not work) that having A7+ chip.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I mean come on Apple! Get it together!

Comment: I don't think your answer is correct. I am using an iPad Pro 9.7 and I am sure this should work for this device that is high end.

Comment: When simulating iOS 13, it will not complain about this.

Answer (score 2):

Try switch the device target to your iOS device (a7+), Metal is not available in iOS simulators.

Answer (score 2):

`CAMetalLayer` is now supported in the iOS 13 / tvOS 13 simulators when running on macOS 10.15. (It is always present but won't be functional if you're running on macOS Mojave).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an oversight in the iOS Simulator in the beta (up to the current beta 2):
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/

It's missing the CAMetalLayer.h

But, if you install the beta onto your iOS device, it *is* there:
/Applications/Xcode6-Beta2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CAMetalLayer.h

Comment: It's missing because there's no x86/desktop implementation of the Metal API and related classes

Answer (score 0):

Please choose the iPhone Device rather than simulators.